# How to direct Back in Time snapshots to a Samba share?

Tags: 12.04, samba

Running a Samba share on a Windows 7 PC. This PC, directs output to my unRAID server.  I can access the share from my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 via Nautilus 3.4.2.  Now I want to run Back In Time snapshots and direct them to the server via my Windows share, but I can't locate the share in BIT.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](https://answers.launchpad.net/backintime/+question/219544) and [this one](https://answers.launchpad.net/backintime/+question/137178).

The first one tells you about how to connect and the second one about possible problems regarding hard-links when backing up.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.